# Laravel OOP with inheritance

Tags: laravel

I'm developing a Laravel application to manage collections of beer items such as glasses and bottles. I currently have a table called beeritems and each item can be of type glass or bottle

```
Schema::create('beeritems', function (Blueprint $table) {
  $table->increments('id');
  $table->unsignedInteger('user_id');
  $table->unsignedInteger('category_id');
  $table->string('item_type');
  $table->string('item_name');
  $table->text('item_description');
  $table->timestamps();
});
```

I have a model called 'BeerItem'. A glass or a bottle share a lot of attributes (e.g. name, description) but some are different. Yet for simplicity I'm storing both glasses and bottles into the beeritems table (some attributes will be null then. I know this is not according to database normalization standards but there's some reasons for it).

To be able to handle the different attributes, I'm doing the following:

```
Route::post('beerglasses/store','BeerglassController@storeBeerglass')->name('beerglasses.store');
Route::post('beerbottles/store','BeerbottleController@storeBeerbottle')->name('beerglasses.store');
```

The idea is that in each controller I can then validate the required attributes and store the object in the 'Beeritem' table using the correct 'item_type'. As attributes can be largely different between a 'bottle' and 'glass'

From a view point of view:

```
public function create(Request $request) {
    //stuff omitted for clarity
    return view('beeritems.create', compact('name'));
```

}

In the view I then differentiate based on the type as depending on the type. some attributes don't need to be shown.

```
@switch( strtolower($name)  )
  @case('beerglasses')
     @include('beeritems.create.beerglass')
     @break
  @case('beerbottles')
     @include('beeritems.create.beerbottle')
     @break
@endswitch
```

This all works but it does not feel right as there is a lot of similar code in each controller. Essentially the store method in each controller is almost identical (it just differs with some attributes).

Can someone hint me to some better solution (with Laravel) keeping a single Beeritem table?

Comment: If I was you, first I would set the bear item type as a new model and not as a string. But as for your question, you've created 2 endpoints, I would use the same one and take the validation into a dedicated validation class (read more about Laravel Requests)

Comment: Why don't you just create a single endpoint and pass a hidden input which indicates the bottle type. Then in your validator, just have a switch or if statement around the specific validation required for one or the other. That would make the most sense to me. In the store function, you could pass an array of data which would be set outside the store function based on what was actually provided. It would really help you from a DRY standpoint to do it this way, but it's still not ideal.

Comment: I can do all this indeed, but  all this feels very procedural. I would hope to do something more object oriented.

Comment: For it to be "correctly" object oriented you should avoid making two separate models share a database table. What you probably want to do in that case is make a parent model that both the Bottle and Glass models extend. Those models would then contain the same base functionality, including the store method, with the only difference being some validation and the front end code for their forms. You would wrap up all their inputs into an array, being careful of mass assignment by guarding their properties, and then you would have shared code with two models that both have separate tables